# Can the material conditional be used in other situations?

Tags: logic, propositions

**Can the material conditional in classical logic (e.g. propositional logic or predicate logic like first-order logic) be used to reason about propositions that are not factual?** E.g., using a subjunctive proposition as in (1a) and (2a):

> (1a) If it snowed in July in Washington DC, I would be amazed. [first proposition subjunctive, second factual]
>
> (2a) If it snowed in July in Washington DC, I would become Emperor of the World. [both propositions subjunctive]

or using a counterfactual proposition as in (1b) and (2b)?:

> (1b) If we had lost WWII, it would be tragic. [fist proposition counterfactual, second factual]
>
> (2b) If we had lost WWII, fascism would have been ruling over the world till this day. [both propositions counterfactual]

Or is plugging in any type of proposition other than factual ones for propositional symbols like 'p' in, say, propositional logic, *conceptually* wrong, probably yielding some anomalous results of sorts?